# android device manager not showing my device

Tags: oneplus-one

My phone was stolen a month ago. I tried to search it with Android Device Manager also but nothing came up.

After few days I searched it again it was not showing my device. What does that mean?

I was using One Plus One.

Answer (score 0):

That mean your device cannot be located. The thief has probably done a factory reset on it. Unfortunately there is a very low chance for you find it back...